# dataReader reader = cmd.executereader() not working

Tags: c#, sql, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I am stuck in simple datareader problem .

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.Sql;

public void proName(string str)
        {
            SqlDataReader reader;
             using (SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
               string proId = textBox3.Text;

               SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT proName FROM products where proId = proId;", sqlcon);
               sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.TableDirect;
               reader = cmd.executereader();


            }
        }
```

and it showing error under cmd / command (the name cmd does not exit in current context) .....

I have tried create object before and after connection but not working.

Comment: with `CommandType.TableDirect` you don't write select

Answer (score 4):

Command type shouldn't be [TableDirect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.commandtype(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text; // which is default
reader = sqlcmd.executereader();
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable name is `sqlcmd` and you're asking for `cmd` on the `executereader()` function.

```
sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.TableDirect;
reader = cmd.executereader();
```

Should be

```
sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.TableDirect;
reader = sqlcmd.executereader();
```

Also consider CharithJ's answer, as he stated:

> Command type shouldn't be TableDirect.

Answer (score 1):

Below should work..

```
using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Data.Sql;
        public void proName(string str)
        {
            SqlDataReader reader;
            using (SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                string proId = textBox3.Text;
                sqlcon.Open();
                SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT proName FROM products where proId = proId;", sqlcon);
                sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                reader = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    Response.Write(reader[0].ToString());

                }

            }
        }
```